# Beyond "i before e, except after c!"

Tags: orthography

What letters of the alphabet are followed the most by the letters *ei*?

Comment: Or when like "a", as in "neighbor" or "weight".

Answer (score 5):

The answer is *r*, largely due to productive prefixes like *re-* and *pre-*.

Per the OED, words with a letter followed by *ei* occur with this frequency for each such letter:

```
 981 r
 586 l
 518 h
 478 w
 394 s
 366 c
 349 v
 341 n
 315 t
 224 d
 149 m
 145 f
 140 b
 139 e
 124 p
 114 g
  81 o
  73 k
  67 u
  51 a
  50 y
  24 i
  19 z
   4 j
   2 x
```

This includes words like *reification, reillumination, reimpregnation* as well ones like *Reichstag, reindeer, reine*.  Because hyphens don’t count, words like *pre-install* are included, since these can be spelled without the hyphen as well.

The main *j*-word is *jeistiecor*. There are also cross references (older spellings) of *jeig* for *jig*, *jeine* for *jean*, and *jeit* for *jet*.

The two *x*-words are *exeime* for *exeme* and *hexeity* for *haecceity*.

Comment: What happens if you don't count words like *reiterate* with that productive prefix?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well, if I do that then you will want me to throw out words like *centreing*, too, eh? :)

Comment: Actually I don't think *centring* should be in the list at all.

Comment: Cool. How do you get lists like that out of the OED? Do you have to have a paid subscription to access that tool?